# Cross tab report spanning to different pages

Tags: crystal-reports

I am very new to crystal reports.
I have a cross tab and it is growing horizontally.Due to this i am getting lot of space in every page after every cross tab.I want to grow my cross tab vertically.
Please helo

Answer (score 0):

Limit number of columns input to the cross tab ane increase number of rows crosstab is displaying.